# Keep in memory database open until JVM exit

Tags: java, sqlite

I'd like to keep an in memory SQLite database, but without attached connections. I'm unit testing a web app, so in `@BeforeAll` method I initialize then in various test methods DDL manipulation. When the last connection is closed, SQLite in memory database is discarded, breaking my tests.

I achieved to keep a H2 in memory database open while the JVM lives:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

But I can't find a way for SQLite. I tried:

```
jdbc:sqlite::memory:&cache=shared
```

But doesn't work. Is it possible?

Comment: are you talking in Android or other Java framework?

Comment: A sqlite in-memory database is freed when the last connection to it is closed. You can't change that behavior.

Comment: I'm using jersey on grizzly server (no android)

Answer (score 0):

As unit-tests are supposed to be independent one another, I would advise against proceeding this way. Depending on the underlying framework you're using you might want to use annotations to drive the execution of initialisation and teardown SQL. For Spring, for example, you can use the following:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-sql

If you can't use annotations or are really determined to proceed down this path (context is everything: you might totally have good reasons) one possibility would be to open an additional connection in your `@BeforeAll` method, which you would then manually close in an `@AfterAll` method. As this would be an additional connection separately managed by your code, sqlite would be tricked into NOT performing its cleanup up until the `@AfterAll` method executes.

If you want this to be at JVM level, you can use a class' static initialiser...